# is there a way to make the testng.xml file to execute in a specfic order

Tags: testng

I have the list of classes to execute. I need to run the classes in the same order which i have specified.

```
<test name="API Suite" preserve-order="true">

    <groups>
        <run>
            <!-- <include name="Set" /> --> 
            <!-- <include name="Get" /> -->  
        </run>
    </groups> 

    <classes>
        <class name="com.api.LoginTest" />  
        <class name="com.api.Collection" />
        <class name="com.api.Entity" />
        <class name="com.api.Acl" />
        <class name="com.api.Attributes" />
        <class name="com.api.Binary" />
        <class name="com.api.User" />
        <class name="com.api.Comment" />
        <class name="com.api.Feedback" />
        <class name="com.api.Event" />
        <class name="com.api.Search" /> 
        <class name="com.api.Subscribe" />
        <class name="com.api.Review" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

I have created two groups set and get in test methods.Some test will run for set and some methods will run for get group.
While running both the groups, it executes in the correct order.
ANd again when I run the get group alone, it executes in the correct order.

Issue I am facing :When I run only the set group, the order violates.

In the search class, it has only get groups. There is no set groups. So when I call the set group, the order violates.
I tried changing one of the get group to set in h class. The suite executes in the correct order. Not sure whats the reason

Please do the needful.

Comment: Could you share your testng.xml. Do you use preserve-order attribute?

Comment: Yes I used preserve-order attribute as true also..  I have two groups. "get"  and "set". The order i specified in the testng.xml is a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j.... In the "h" class i dont have the "set" group at all. I have only the "get" group.When I made a method to "set" it runs in  the correct order.

Comment: Show your xml .. question is not clear

Comment: I have added  my xml file.

Comment: here "search" is the class where i doesnt have set group. When I start running the set group alone, the subscribe executed after collection and the review executed after entity. But when I made one method in the search class as "set" all the classes executed in the correct order,

Comment: Why do you have the groups and classes both in your xml ? You can run the classes in the order you want by just putting them in the test tag and having that preser-order attribute set

Comment: What is the wrong order you see with get only group?